# When is "diēs" masculine, when is it feminine, and why can this word take different genders?

Tags: etymology, declension, gender

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dies#Inflection) goes into it a bit:

> *Diēs* is an exceptional case of a fifth declension noun since it is both used in the masculine form and in the feminine form, instead of just feminine like the rest of the fifth declension nouns. The masculine use is more common, and almost invariably used for the plural. The feminine use is found in the singular when the day is being personified as a goddess, when it refers to a specific day (e.g., the date of a letter, or an appointed day for business), when it refers to the passing of time, and occasionally in other contexts.

But why, etymologically, is this the case? Why these different categories? Do we have evidence that these uses change over time?

Comment: I've been told that it's masculine in Classical Latin and feminine in Ecclesiastical Latin at least since Middle Ages. But I don't know why (and when exactly) the shift occured.

Comment: Haec dies, quam fecit Dominus, exultemus...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I believe there's no straightforward answer as to „why different usage contexts correlate to different grammatical gender“, but the etymological origin gives some insights to the gender.

*Diēs* comes from Proto-Indo-European *d(i)jéus „daytime sky, Sky-god“ and is cognate to *Iūp-piter* (≈ *Diespiter*, „dies pater“), so originally it should have been masculine, as it is the name of a father god (= Vedic *dyauḥ [pitā]* or Greek Ζεῦς [πατήρ]):

> The Latin forms Diespiter, Dispiter, U. di, dei together with the word diēs ‘day’ point to the generalization of a stem *dijē-, whereas Iūpiter, Iovis reflect PIt. *djow-. These can be derived from a single PIE paradigm for ‘(god of the) sky, day-light’, which phonetically split in two in PIt. and yielded two new stems with semantic specialization. Syllabic *dij- in the nom.acc.sg. can stem from the oblique cases (gen.sg. *diwos, etc.), in which syllabic *di- occurred. The acc.sg. *dijēm led to the creation of a new nom.sg. *dijēs and a separate paradigm meaning ‘day’ <..>

(Michiel de Vaan, *Etymological Dictionary of Latin and the Other Italic Languages*, Brill, 2008)

As for feminine *diēs*, I guess that it might be a paradigm-leveling – fifth declension is regularly feminine, *diēs* is the only masculine exception, so by analogy it would be inclined to become feminine too. However, I am not sure if this is exactly the factor, I couldn't find a source – please suggest one or disprove this.

Answer (score 14):

I can only partially answer your question. In medieval documents *dies* is sometimes feminine where based on classical usage we would expect it to be masculine. Examples:

1. *Liber Pontificalis*<sup>1</sup> (~10th century) 371, in reference to Charlemagne's arrival in Rome (but note that this text contains frequent grammatical irregularities):

> Et **alia die**, secundum olitanam consuetudinem, natale beati Andreae
>   apostoli celebrantes, Roma introeunte cum mole gaudio et laetitia in
>   patriarchio Lateranense introivit.

2. Ekkhart (12th century) uses *dies* in the feminine in all of its three occurrences in the excerpts in Sidwell.<sup>2</sup> (But it could be that these are feminine because they refer to the *dies dicta* of the meeting between Henry IV and the Pope.)

   - "quam  ingenti  periculo,  quam  varia disceptatione  **tota  dies illa**  consumpta  sit"
   - "quod et impigre fecit et usque ad **inclinatam iam diem**"
   - "Sic denique **ea die** *gloria in excelsis Deo et in terra pax hominibus 
     bonae voluntatis*, ut ita dicam, est recuperata"
3. Roger Bacon (13th century), in the DMLBS<sup>3</sup> (but from which Bacon text I don't know): "dicitur ... dies alia longior esse".
4. See elsewhere in the DMLBS entry, where *dies* is used in either gender, e.g. *dies festus/festivus* vs. *dies festiva*.

#### References

1. *Le Liber Pontiﬁcalis: Texte, Introduction et Commentaire*, vol. II. 1892. Ed. L’Abbé L. Duchesne.
2. Sidwell, Keith. 1995. *Reading Medieval Latin*. At 12.3.ii-iii, pp. 202-203.
3. *Dictionary of Medieval Latin from British Sources* [ad loc. via Logeion](http://logeion.uchicago.edu/index.html#dies).

Comment: What is DMLBS? Thanks.

Comment: @Figulus Hi! DMLBS is the Dictionary of Medieval Latin from British Sources, which you can view in the "DMLBS" lexicon tab at Logeion: https://logeion.uchicago.edu/dies. (The lexicon tabs are not at the top of the page, but partway down.)

Answer (score 11):

The *OLD* writes that *dies* is "fem. frequently or usually in senses 1b, 5, 7, 10, occasionally elsewhere," with the following definitions listed:

- 1b: [the period from sunrise to sunset] as a deity
- 5: A specific day, the date of a letter
- 7: A day appointed for business
- 10: The lapse or passing of time

You might want to scope out the *OLD* for more about those definitions — lots of good, broad examples.

For what it's worth, I have always used the first part of Ovid *Met* 10.270 (from the Pygmalion episode) to help me remember that specific days/festival days are generally feminine:

> *Festa dies Veneris...*

Comment: Funny—I've always used the Dies Iræ: *Diés íræ, diés illa solvet sæclum in favilla...*

Comment: @JoelDerfner Just don't use the Sign of the Cross to remember the classical genitive singular of *filius*.

Comment: @CMonsour Oh, dear—I'm afraid that went over my head. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: @JoelDerfner The classical form is *fili*, but the Sign of the Cross is post-classical and uses *filii*.

Answer (score 5):

*Diēs* was originally an irregular member of the *fourth* declension: in Old Latin the nom. was *diūs*. But the irregular acc. *diēm* tended to generate a new nominative by analogy, and the noun was pulled into the emerging fifth declension while keeping its gender.  These 12 or so nouns don't represent any identifiable group of PIE nouns, but slowly became more similar to each other over time; *rēs*, for example, was originally thoroughly irregular.  Many of them are defective in the plural, either altogether or in particular cases only.

Comment: Welcome to the site and thanks for the answer!